# woocommerce кнопка "применить фильтр" работает ко всем группам фильтров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

В woocommerce кнопка "применить фильтр" работает ко всем 2м группам фильтров, когда мне надо чтобы Главный фильтр не зависел от просто Фильтр, в котором и лежит эта кнопка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эта картинка не от WC.

Comment: Почему бы не написать в службу поддержки плагина, это премиум плагин ведь.